# Conda update failed in python script and pass on CMD window

Tags: python, miniconda

I'm trying to update a python environment in miniconda, using a yaml file.

I tried it in 2 ways -

1. When I run the command `subprocess.run("conda env update -n env2 -f path_to_yaml_file")` in a python script (the python interpreter is a in an existing python-miniconda environment (env1), and I updating a differed environment (env2)), it fail with the following message:

   `ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\2\\pip-uninstall-5c5jvd44\\normalizer.exe'                                                                                                                                                                        Consider using the '--user' option or check the permissions.             CondaValueError: pip returned an error`
2. When I'm running the same command `conda env update -n env2 -f path_to_yaml_file` in a CMD window, it update the environment successfully.

Does anyone knows what is the cause of the difference between the 2 actions? How can I resolve it?

Clerifications:

1. I can not add the `--user` option to a `conda update` command, because it is a pip option and not a conda option.
2. The miniconda folder is under `C:\Users\Administrator`

Answer (score 0):

Update normalizer to the newest version fixed it